# KVC on id type conforming to a protocol

Tags: objective-c, kvc

I have stumbled upon a problem with key value coding in Xcode 6. It seems as it's impossible to use key value coding on id's conforming to a protocol.

When a property is declared as id the compiler agrees

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id foo;

[foo setValue:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
```

When I set the id to conform to a protocol I get a compiler error. "No known instance method for selector ...".

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<MyProtocol> foo;

[foo setValue:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
```

It works if I set the type to NSObject, like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject<MyProtocol> *foo;

[foo setValue:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
```

The protocol "MyProtocol" conforms to NSObject, but as far as I understand the object is required to be a subclass of NSObject in order for KVC to work. But why does the first scenario work but not the second?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with KVC specifically; `id s = @"WATERMELONS"; [s lowercaseString]; id <MyProtocol> r = s; [r lowercaseString];` has the same result.

Comment: Ok, guess it makes sense. So you're no longer allowed to send any message to id's conforming a protocol?

Comment: `id` is a free-for-all; the compiler just knows that the thing is an ObjC object. When you specify a protocol, you've restricted the type slightly -- you're basically saying "I don't care what this really is as long as it has methods from `MyProtocol`" -- but it looks like the compiler takes that as restrictively as possible. _Only_ methods from that protocol will compile. I don't know why, though; there may be reason in type theory.

Comment: But this is new in Xcode 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't new in Xcode 6.  (I just tested Xcode 5.1.1 and got an error.)  The rules are:

- The compiler will let you send any message to a bare `id`.
- The compiler will only let you send a message to `id<Protocol1, Protocol2, Protocol3, ...>` if the message is defined by one of the named protocols.
- The compiler will only let you send a message to `SomeClass<Protocol1, Protocol2, Protocol3, ...>` if the message is defined by one of the named protocols, **or** by the class.  Messages defined by the class include messages defined by its superclasses and its categories.

The `setValue:forKey:` method is defined in the [`NSKeyValueCoding` category](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) on the [`NSObject` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  It's not defined on the [`NSObject` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject).

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can think of for the restrictiveness of this protocol type checking?

Comment: I guess it's to help you avoid mistakes.  It's easy to cast to `id` if you know what you're doing, but hard to get guidance from the IDE if it thinks every message is valid.